# Mussolini on Nietzsche

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche, politics

Does anyone have a link / explanation of Mussolini's writings on Nietzsche?

Failing that, any of the early fascists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote ascribed to Mussolini by *Renzo De Felice, Mussolini il rivoluzionario, Einaudi 2004*. From wikipedia (italian):

> Il superuomo, ecco la grande creazione nietzscheana! Quale impulso segreto, quale interna rivolta hanno suggerito al solitario professore di lingue antiche dell'Università di Basilea questa superba nozione? Forse il taedium vitae, della vita quale si svolge nelle odierne società civili dove irrimediabile mediocrità trionfa a danno della pianta-uomo. E Nietzsche suona la diana di un prossimo ritorno all'ideale. Ma un ideale diverso fondamentalmente da quello in cui hanno creduto le generazioni passate. Per comprenderlo verrà una nuova specie di spiriti liberi fortificati nella guerra, nella solitudine, nel grande pericolo, spiriti che conosceranno il ghiaccio e i venti, le nevi dell'alta montagna e sapranno misurare con occhio sereno tutta la profondità degli abissi, spiriti dotati di un genere sublime di perversità, spiriti che ci libereranno dall'amore del prossimo della volontà del nulla ridonando alla terra il suo scopo e agli uomini le loro speranze – spiriti nuovi, liberi, molto liberi che trionferanno su Dio e sul Nulla!

See also *Mussolini, Benito: La filosofia della forza. 1908*

Comment: yeah looking at google translate it's just (presumably awful) *verse*. i was arguing with someone that fascism isn't terrible philosophy, it's not philosophy at all

Comment: Yes, also for me it sounds awfully overreaching. Though one can hear the original, i.e., Nietzsche's Zarathustra.

Comment: it too is trying to persuade and knows it. not sure about anything else

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://forum.termometropolitico.it/657284-benito-mussolini-filosofia.html

I think this is a very revealing piece by Mussolini from November to December 1908, setting out Mussolini's elitist propensities and attraction to a philosophy of overpowering force.

It is in Italian, but if you do not know Italian too well, put passages through google translate and though not perfect, it can give you a sense of Mussolini's commitment to violence or 'forza'.